# Feedly API help required

Tags: feedly

Can any API programmers answer a question about the Feedly API? I would like to know what these mean exactly in the Feedly API: Score, Coverage, CoverageScore and EstimatedEngagement.

Answer (score 0):

These are leftovers from experiments we ran in our feed search engine.

- "coverage" and "coverageScore" are roughly based on the ratio of entries read vs. entries published (higher score = readers are more likely to read entries published by this source).
- "estimatedEngagement" is an average value for the engagement of entries published by this source (see the entries API for details).
- "score" is a compound value of these and other values; it was used to showcase the best sources in the search results.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou.  What is the "value for engagement"?  And I'm wondering about 1 more:  what does "LastUpdated"  mean?

Comment: "engagement" is a measure of reader engagement (sharing, save to board). "lastUpdated" is the timestamp of the newest entry from this source.

Comment: Thank you.  Also, we have an issue with speed.  The feed from Feedly is extraordinarily slow.   Is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: Can you provide the feedId? Also, what is slow? Is the server slow to respond, or is the feed not refreshed often enough?